# YouTube Data API v3 allowed referers for browser app key not working as expected

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-api, youtube-api

I am struggling trying to configure the new YouTube Data API v3 correctly. I need to access the API from a Google Chrome extension. I already created an API key from [Google APIs Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console), more precisely a **Key for browser apps (with referers)** key. Having the **allowed referers** set to blank, all the referers are allowed and everything works ok.

However, this key is embedded on my Chrome extension and therefore public to everybody. Anyone could use my key to make requests, polluting my stats and wasting my quota limits. I understand the **allowed referes** field is to avoid this situation. Tracking my API request's headers, I can see that my `Origin` is the following:

`chrome-extension://myExtensionId`

Also, in the response from the API, I can see the following header:

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: chrome-extension://myExtensionId`

So everything seems to work correctly. However, if I set the **allowed referers** field to `chrome-extension://myExtensionId`, it doesn't work, I get something like an "access not configured" error. What am I doing wrong?

My guess is that the **allowed referers** field can only work with HTTP referers, but in that case this is a really annoying limitation for extension developers. Any schema should be okay for the **allowed referers** field, I would say.

Comment: Chrome extensions do not include the `Referer` Header in their requests, hence the "Allowed referers" option does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone can sign up for access to the YouTube Data API v3. I understand your concern about leaking your API key, but since no one would actually benefit from using your key versus just registering their own, I don't think this is something to worry about in practice.

Comment: Well, it's a security problem, in my opinion. Unfortunately evil people exist. I also think no one actually benefits from war, but war happens all the time in this sad world. Wouldn't be just awesome and logical to include that `Referer` header set to `chrome-extension://myExtensionId` in the extension XMLHttpRequests so that you can set that field in Google APIs Console, as if you were using it from a regular webpage?

Comment: Btw, just in case you know the answer to my other related question also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15166868/youtube-data-api-v3-daily-quotas-and-per-user-limits

Comment: How is this an answer?

The issue applies to all Google APIs (I'm interested in Google Translate, which definitely IS NOT FREE).

Since Chrome Extensions run from a user's browser, not my website, I can't limit by HTTP referrer...