# XMLHttpRequest succeeds without manifest permissions? Maybe CORS?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain, google-api, youtube-api

I have developed a Google Chrome extensions that uses YouTube Data API **v2**. My permission field in the manifest looks like this, because the script is injected in pages under youtube.com and I also need access to tabs:

```
"permissions": ["tabs", "*://*.youtube.com/*"]
```

This also works when I do a request to YouTube Data API **v2** because the request is done to http://gdata.youtube.com/, so it is the same domain. But now I am migrating to YouTube Data API **v3**, and the requests must be done to http://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/ (note **HTTPS** instead of HTTP also). However, surprisingly, *my requests are working perfectly without adding any new permission*.

I know, I am asking something that doesn't seem to be a problem, but personally I consider any behavior that I don't understand in my software a problem. Why does this happen? Am I not supposed to add a permission such as `"*://*.googleapis.com/*"` in order for my XMLHttpRequest requests to the API to work?

I also have **some king of guess** about this: [HTTP Access Control headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). My requests do send a `Origin` header with value `chrome-extension://myExtensionId`. And the answer from the API also contains the following header:

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: chrome-extension://myExtensionId`

But could this be the reason Chrome is allowing me to do a cross-origin XMLHttpRequest without any extra permission defined in the manifest? Not sure, and apparently this is not documented anywhere in Google APIs, YouTube Data API v3 or Chrome Extensions developer documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If Chrome does not find the permission in the manifest, it treats a request as a normal request. This means that a request will still succeed when the right [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) headers are set. Otherwise, a request will fail because of the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

The Google API JavaScript library explicitly mentions support for CORS:

> [**Making a request: Option 3**](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/wiki/GettingStarted#Making_a_request%3a_Option_3)
>   Google APIs support CORS. Please visit the CORS page for more information on using CORS to make requests.

If possible, I still recommend adding the permission to the manifest file. For [simple requests](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#simple-method), this does not bring any advantages. For non-simple requests, this will half the number of requests: Non-simple requests are always preceeded by a preflight (OPTIONS) request which checks if the client is permitted to access the source.

By adding the permission to the manifest file, Chrome will not fall back to CORS, and always use one network request to complete the request. Great!
However... you might think again if you're the author of an already-deployed extension. When new origin permissions are added to the manifest file, the extension will be disabled until the user approves the extension. The dialog box shows "Remove extension" and "Enable" next to each other, so there's a chance of loosing the user.

If you wish, you can overcome this problem by using an [optional permission](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions.html), activated at the options page. Clearly explain in layman language that the option will improve the speed of the extension, and don't forget to mention that additional permissions will be requested.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this clear and detailed answer! My guess was not so wrong then. And you are right, last time I increased permissions for my [currently published extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/youtube-ratings-preview/cgbhdenfmgbagncdmgbholejjpmmiank) I lost about 50% of the users and got a huge amount of 1-star ratings. I just needed "tabs" permission to show a pageAction, but the warning message was shocking ("access to all your browsing history" or something similar). And as all my requests are _simple_ I have decided not to add the new permission. Never again.

Comment: Btw, just in case you also know the answer to a related question I have also made recently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15166758/youtube-data-api-v3-allowed-referers-for-browser-app-key-not-working-as-expected