# CORS 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: cors, iis-8

I have been following the [Mozilla article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) on how to set up my website to allow **Cross-site scripting requests**. Using IIS Manager I have added the following HTTP Response Headers

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin  : *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers : Origin, SecurityPrivateKeyID
Access-Control-Allow-Methods : GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
```

Despite this I keep getting a `405 Method Not Allowed` when my browsers (Firefox and Chrome) send the pre-flight request with a custom `SecurityPrivateKeyID` header.

Request

```
OPTIONS /Service/Json/User.svc/ HTTP/1.1
Host: serviceprovider.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Origin: http://client.com
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers: securityprivatekeyid
Connection: keep-alive
```

Response

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Allow: GET
Content-Length: 1565
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
access-control-allow-origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, SecurityPrivateKeyID
Date: Sat, 23 Mar 2013 08:35:03 GMT
```

The service works fine when accessing directly at `http://serviceprovider.com/Service/Json/User.svc/`.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

[note I have changed my hosts files to point client.com and serviceprovider.com at my machine]

[a solution using JSONP will not do as my web service must be able to consume POST, PUT and DELETE methos]

Comment: are you using jquery ajax?

Comment: @Floradu88 No, standard javascript using XMLHTTPRequest

Comment: then this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667519/firefox-setting-to-enable-cross-domain-ajax-request or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15167738/xmlhttprequest-succeeds-without-manifest-permissions-maybe-cors

Answer (score 25, accepted):

My IIS 8 instance is fresh installation, it seems I needed to make some modifications to the `Handler Mappings`

### Backup IIS Configuration

In the event that any of the sugggested changes break your existing websites it's best to make a backup of the applicationhost.config file

1. Navigate to `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config`
2. Make a copy of `applicationhost.config`

### Remove Unused Handlers

As a starting point I removed all unused Handler Mappings to reduce the problem space. You can do this by modifying the `applicationhost.config` directly or by using IIS Manager

1. Open IIS Manager
2. Either on the server node or the individual website node select the Handler Mappings feature
3. Manually remove all mappings that you don't need.

My websites are heavily service based and just depend on static files and files with the `.aspx` and `.svc` files extensions. I also manually removed all references to `.NET 2.0` throughout the configuration file.

### Add OPTIONS Handler

This seems to be the fix.

1. Open IIS Manager
2. Either on the server node or the individual website node select the Handler Mappings feature
3. In the lefthand column select `Add Module Mapping`
4. In the `Add Module Mapping` dialog use the following values.

   - `Request path` - `*`
   - `Module` - `ProtocolSupportModule`
   - `Executable` - [Leave blank]
   - `Name` - [Whatever you want]
5. Click `Request Restrictions`

   - In the `Mapping` tab, unckeck `Invoke handler only if request is mapped to`
   - In the `Verbs` tab ensure `OPTIONS` is selected
   - In the `Access` tab select `Script`

My resulting Handlers configuration looks like this

```
<handlers accessPolicy="Read, Script">
    <add name="OPTIONS" path="*" verb="OPTIONS" modules="ProtocolSupportModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    <add name="svc-Integrated-4.0" path="*.svc" verb="*" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpHandlerFactory, System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    <add name="SecurityCertificate" path="*.cer" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll" resourceType="File" />
    <add name="ISAPI-dll" path="*.dll" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Execute" allowPathInfo="true" />
    <add name="PageHandlerFactory-Integrated-4.0" path="*.aspx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    <add name="CGI-exe" path="*.exe" verb="*" modules="CgiModule" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Execute" allowPathInfo="true" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" responseBufferLimit="0" />
    <add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Read" />
</handlers>
```

Comment: In the Verbs part you say to select All Verbs but on your config file the verb is set to OPTIONS, what is the correct one?

Comment: @Paleta I don't have access to the configuration anymore but please assume that the xml config is correct. Hopefully someone will correct my answer.

Comment: @Paleta It seems the xml is correct to limit the verb to `OPTIONS`. When we set it to `ALL VERBS` as described in the text it only partially worked.

Comment: @AnthonyElliott I've changed step 5.2 to match the xml.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, but unfortunately it didn't worked for me (I'm using IIS 7.5). After 2 days of research, the only working solution I found to avoid "405 Method Not Allowed" was to define the CORS headers in the `Application_BeginRequest` method, as mentioned in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/14631068/827168

Comment: Removing all the handers seemed to do the trick for me, an easy way of doing that is simply to add a clear-element at the top of handlers in my web sites Web.config. `<handlers><clear />...`

Comment: this worked for me (sort of) I had to add one of the lines above directly into the web.config though.     <add name="OPTIONS" path="*" verb="OPTIONS" modules="ProtocolSupportModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />

Answer (score 2):

For my instance:

1. Make sure the "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" and "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" in request is less or equal than that in response.(Don't use "*")
2. Remove this line `<remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />` in Web.config

Comment: Setting all CORS related headers + removing that line did the trick for me

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had to go `Handler Mappings`, switch to `Ordered View`, then move `OPTIONSVerbHandler` all the way to the top of the list.

Comment: This solved my issue. web.confg file updated with new handler mapping order. Thanks for the tip!