# Cross domain azure

Tags: azure, cross-domain

I created two web applications. One is a web site that mainly contains of js files.
Second site is a REST based service site. Web site is doing CRUD operations against Rest services.

I already hosted Rest services in Azure.

I want to host web site in Azure. What is the best way to deal with the cross domain issues ?

Comment: Will the call to REST based service site be made from JS in the web application or will it be done through some code behind?

Comment: It will call to Rest from js files through jquery ajax

Comment: Do take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18981339/http-options-request-on-azure-websites-fails-due-to-cors. Essentially you will have to set up CORS settings in web.config file.