# Windows Azure: PHP Website Cross Domain request

Tags: php, iis, azure

I am hosting my PHP web app on Windows Azure Websites and it's loading data from Windows Azure Blob Storage. This results in cross domain request error. How do I resolve it?

Comment: See if this thread solves your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18981339/http-options-request-on-azure-websites-fails-due-to-cors.

Comment: php has no cross-domain issues. it can talk to any host you tell it to. Do you mean maybe some client-side Javascript is having trouble?