# Font-awesome icons not showing in Wordpress after URL redirect

Tags: wordpress, azure, font-awesome

I have Font Awesome icons on our site and they work fine on the Azure-hosted page at [this url](http://usmedit.azurewebsites.net/).

However when the DNS setting was redirected to our main url, the icons simply don't show up and turn into blank boxes.
[Here's how it looks like now](http://usmedicalit.com/).

I've tried Wordpress support but they were not able to figure out what happened. I'm unsure whether this was a theme issue (the theme used is Evolve) or if it's because of Font Awesome or Azure. Looking for suggestions or tips I can try out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

"GET http://usmedit.azurewebsites.net/wp-content/themes/evolve/library/media/js/fontawesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.3.0"

Please check if your font files in the right place.

"Font from origin has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://usmedicalit.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404."

See this post: Azure Cloud Service CDN font CORS error -[Azure Cloud Service CDN font CORS error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140790/azure-cloud-service-cdn-font-cors-error)