# OPTIONS 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So I'm attempting to get a progress bar on file uploads on my site. If I simply upload the resource

```
$.ajax({
    url: $rootScope.URL,  //Server script to process data
    type: 'POST',
    beforeSend: beforeSendHandler,
    success: completeHandler,
    error: errorHandler,
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
});
```

It works perfectly, however if I add the event to listen to progress:

```
$.ajax({
    url: $rootScope.URL,  //Server script to process data
    type: 'POST',
    xhr: function() {  // Custom XMLHttpRequest
        var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        if(myXhr.upload){ // Check if upload property exists
            myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',progressHandlingFunction, false); // For handling the progress of the upload
        }
        return myXhr;
    },
    beforeSend: beforeSendHandler,
    success: completeHandler,
    error: errorHandler,
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
});
```

I get:

```
OPTIONS myserver.com/controller/filtercontroller.php? 405 (Method Not Allowed)
  jQuery.ajaxTransport.send 
  jQuery.extend.ajax    
  (anonymous function)  
  jQuery.event.dispatch 
  jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle  
XMLHttpRequest cannot load myserver.com/controller/filtercontroller.php?. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63342' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.
```

So obviously my server doesn't have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `OPTIONS` right? But the top 2 lines of `filtercontroller.php` are:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
```

I've tried several different solutions and none have worked for me.

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Headers may not not allow * as accepted value, depending on the server/client implementation - http://stackoverflow.com/a/8719346/2155068

Comment: 405 is usually issued by the web server itself. So you might check the configuration of your web server.

Comment: @MjrKusanagi that is irrelevant in this case -- Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * is an acceptable value.

Comment: Just to confirm -- there is literally nothing else at the top of that php script, correct? It's literally <?php and those two function calls?

Comment: Yes the first lines of the file are
                           
   `<?php

    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');`

Comment: Okay, and you've checked the response using a browser inspector and those headers aren't there?

Comment: Could you elaborate on that. The error appears in the console between the call and the progressHandlingFunction getting called, in that function a XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent is passed in, then errorHandler gets called an object and the string "error" are passed to it.

Comment: Can anyone help with this?

Comment: It seems your JS is running on WebStorm.
Can you check which headers are sent? Do you read some headers? 
You could add `header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');` and `header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-header1, X-header2');`

Comment: Have you tried setting "withCredentials" in the ajax call like so?:`xhrFields: {  withCredentials: true } `

Comment: Could you try to add this event handler in the ``beforeSendHandler``? The function given there will receive ``XMLHttpRequest`` as it's first parameter. You can register your listeners here like this: XMLHttpRequest.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
  // Handle progress
  beforeSendHandler();
}, false);

Comment: @ReyGe with credentials didn't help.

Comment: @MartijnR I got Cannot read property 'addEventListenerListener' of undefined

Comment: @CWürtz The first header is already present, adding the second header didn't change anything.

Comment: The anonymous function is corrupting your headers. I can only assume that `progressHandlingFunction` is the anonymous function. Please add it to your post and explain where it exists in scope and enclosure level.

Comment: I've changed out the anonymous function call for a named function, it sits on the same scope level as every other handling function. All it does is take a progress event and attempt to spit out the percent.

function progressHandlingFunction(e){
            var pc = parseInt(100 - (e.loaded / e.total * 100));
            toastr.success(pc + "%");
        }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, first of all I do not think it has anything to do with your CORS configuration, as it would output different errors. Looking into what can cause the error you are receiving in the context of Azure/IIS I found the following possibilities:

- You might have an explicit `<remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />` in your `web.config` file. (This is the default in certain cases).
- The WebDAV module is [interfering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15619075/webapi-delete-not-working-405-method-not-allowed) and you should add `<remove name="WebDAVModule"/>`

Lastly I just found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19091291/1266242) which might offer some different solutions where you do not set the CORS headers in your PHP file, but instead set them in the server configuration.

Comment: Thank you so much. Changing the remove name resolved the 405 error, but not the Access-Control-blah-blah error, that was resolved by following the link you provided and adding in the custom headers. Enjoy your bounty.

Answer (score 0):

The `header()` must be placed before ANY output is sent to the browser, once output is sent to the browser the `header()` will actually throw a PHP warning which if you aren't seeing isn't being displayed or tracked.

Alternatively you can also do it through .htaccess which would be processed before any of your PHP scripts. This is going on the asumption that you are using apache for your webserver.

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
# below line shouldn't be needed as by default all of those are allowed,
# if you were doing PUT, TRACE, DELETE, etc then you would need it
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, OPTIONS"
```

Comment: The headers are the first lines of code:

    <?php

    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');

Comment: Did you try the .htaccess method?

Comment: The server isn't running apache.

Comment: this answer should solve the problem it's basically what I posted but for azure. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18981339/http-options-request-on-azure-websites-fails-due-to-cors