# Form post using promise not working

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

I am working on user registration form in Angular 4. My RestApi is working fine. I have tried using postman. I dont know why the form is not being post.

I get following error in console header:

```
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 405 Method Not Allowed
```

I have tried the following code.

register.component.html

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onRegister(userForm)" #userForm="ngForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="enter email" [(ngModel)]="user.email" name="email" #email = "ngModel" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" required>
        <div *ngIf="email.invalid && (email.dirty || email.touched)"
        class="alert alert-danger">
            <div *ngIf = "email.errors?.required">Email field can't be blank</div>
            <div *ngIf = "email.errors?.pattern && email.touched">The email id doesn't seem right</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!userForm.form.valid">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

register.component.ts

```
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {

    private user: User;
    userForm: FormGroup;
    // constructor(private auth: AuthService, private http: Http) {}
    constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder, private auth: AuthService, private http: Http) { } // form builder simplify form initialization


    ngOnInit() {
        this.user = new User({
            email:"", 
            password: { password: "" , confirmPassword: ""}, 
        })
    }

    onRegister(): void {
        console.log("this is me", this.user);
        this.auth.register(this.user)
        .then((user) => {
            // console.log(user.json());
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }

}
```

auth.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    private BASE_URL: string = 'http://myapp.local/public_html';
    private headers: Headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

constructor(private http: Http) {}

// register = function(user) {
register(user): Promise<any> {
    console.log("This is registration page service", user);
    let url: string = `${this.BASE_URL}/user`;
    console.log("url", url);
    return this.http.post(url, user).toPromise();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

As part of the POST, try set the `contentType` to `application/json`. You do this by supplying the `headers` to your post.

```
register(user): Promise<any> {
    const headers: Headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    const requestOptions = new RequestOptions({
        headers: headers
    });

    console.log("This is registration page service", user);
    let url: string = `${this.BASE_URL}/user`;
    console.log("url", url);
    return this.http.post(url, user, requestOptions).toPromise();
}
```

Also, on the server side, depending on the framework that you use, make sure that you specify `HttpMethod` as `Post`.

In your service code you have defined `Headers` object but you are not sending it as part of your request.

In addition, have a look at these two posts that deal with a similar issue:

[OPTIONS 405 (Method Not Allowed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30575539/options-405-method-not-allowed#30685039)

[WebAPI Delete not working - 405 Method Not Allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15619075/webapi-delete-not-working-405-method-not-allowed)

Comment: Yes I have tried with your solutions but still the result is the same

Comment: Which server-side technology are you using? ASP.NET, PHP? Are you trying to use CORS as well?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know much about PHP. You'll have to see your server configuration (I guess it is Apache) and see how to remove the limits for the OPTIONS HTTP method.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try by changing method to "POST" ? Could be the case that your method expects "POST" on the end point and you're  sending it via "GET"

Comment: return this.http.get(url, user).toPromise(); I have tried using get, i can retrieve data. my problem is with post

Comment: Can you check google chrome console network tab to see header, request and response ? It'd would help you to identify what you're actually posting. Check the Method , it should be POST there.

Comment: Yes I have checked it. Response says "Method Not Allowed" and header message has Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 405 Method Not Allowed. I have already mentioned them in my question