# Access HTTPS wcf service in HTML,Javascript, service and Web page hosted on different domains - CORS

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cors

I am trying to access WCF service hosted on server. The service is using SSL connection.
I assigned a self signed certificate in IIS.
The service is a restfull service. 
I tried with two different scenarios:

1st scenario : 
I hosted the web site to same server(client application which access service)
In this case the service is accessible and able to get response from service.

2nd scenario : 
I hosted the web site to localhost,local machine. 
From here when I am trying to make request to service method which is hosted on different web server it is not accessible. 
Showing error "Method not allowed"
Here is code :

```
function testHttps()
  {

jsonText3=JSON.stringify({"Name":"Avinash"});
url="https://ServerIP/WcfSecureService/Service.svc/GetName";
    var xhr = createCORSRequest('POST', url);
    if (!xhr) {
      alert('CORS not supported');
    }

    xhr.onload = function() {          

        alert(xhr.responseText);
    };

        xhr.onerror = function() {
        alert('Woops, there was an error making the request.');         
    };

    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json') ;
    xhr.send(jsonText3);
        }


function createCORSRequest(method, url)
    {
       var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        if ("withCredentials" in xhr) 
          {         
           xhr.open(method, url, true);    
           } 
           else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") 
          {   
           xhr = new XDomainRequest();
           xhr.open(method, url);
         } else
     {
    xhr = null;
    } 
   return xhr;
  }
```

How to make CORS call success with HTTPS?
I do not want to install any certificate on client site. 
How to authenticate service from Javascript?

Please suggest...
Thanks for your help in advance.

--Avinash

Comment: Any one has idea on this !!!!
Please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this](http://enable-cors.org/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15584909/cors-405-method-not-allowed) out.

I think your problem is not about https: is the server responding with an header like the following?

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

In case it's not, it's probably filtering out your local referer.

Furthermore, if you're using credentials the server can't use the "*" wildcard and has to specify every allowed domains, which don't include localhost, I guess.