# Angular $http CORS 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: angularjs, http, cors, http-status-code-405

I'm tring to GET from a api system with angular $http.get module but :

**api endpoint system just accept GET method and won't work with OPTION method**

REQUEST headers :

```
Host: www.example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers: x-device-type,x-software-version,x-unit-measurement
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Connection: keep-alive
```

RESPONSE headers:

Status code: **405 Method Not Allowed**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Accept, origin, referring-domain, X-UNIT-MEASUREMENT, X-AUTH-TOKEN, X-DEVICE-TYPE, X-SOFTWARE-VERSION
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Allow: GET
Cache-Control: private,no-transform
Content-Length: 1565
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 14 Apr 2016 11:41:13 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-API-VERSION: 1.40.1.0
X-INSTANCE-ID: ALL
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-origin: *
p3p: CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"
```

I just tried this things :

1: setting default Content-Type even text/plain and other types **[Not Working]**

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] ='application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8';
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15584909/cors-405-method-not-allowed have you checked it?

Comment: unfortunately I don't access to api server to edit config files

Comment: have you tried making jsonp request?

Comment: jsonp working well but I can't set X headers to jsonp and In other side I have POST DELETE and other methods too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I'm using Atom Electron shell for running my app , the quick solution for me was using `--disable-web-security` for disabling CORS protection in browser .