# Exchange on-premise OWA REST API not handling CORS preflight correctly

Tags: iis, cors, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, outlook-web-app

I currently have an Exchange 2019 on-premise server setup to test my OWA add-in. I'm calling the `api/v2.0/me/messages/{id}` endpoint from my add-in. Everything works just fine with hitting the cloud (Office 365), but against the on-prem Exchange I get a `405 Method Not Allowed` back for the CORS preflight OPTIONS header request.

I have tried the fixes recommended by - [IIS hijacks CORS Preflight OPTIONS request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22495240/iis-hijacks-cors-preflight-options-request),
[Handling CORS Preflight requests to ASP.NET MVC actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13624386/handling-cors-preflight-requests-to-asp-net-mvc-actions), and  https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/getting-started-with-the-iis-cors-module

The response from the server for the CORS request contains the following as I'd expect -

```
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-allow-headers: Origin, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
access-control-allow-methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
```

Is there something IIS or Exchange specific needed to enable CORS for this scenario?

Comment: make sure you install the iis cors module. remove the unused Handlers. and try to add the Add OPTIONS Handler. try to follow this link detailed steps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15584909/cors-405-method-not-allowed

Comment: I have done all of those steps. It looks like the OWA REST API isn't supported on-premise at this time - https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/991#issuecomment-590652863