# AJAX and GOOGLEAPIS.COM

Tags: security, ajax

I do know for a fact (because I use it myself) that plain AJAX calls successfully reach the host at ajax.googleapis.com
This seems to violate the rule that such calls should only go to the originating server, i.e. mine.
How do browsers know it is ok to break this rule when comes to googleapis.com and, possibly, some others hosts?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: possible duplicate of [XMLHttpRequest succeeds without manifest permissions? Maybe CORS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15167738/xmlhttprequest-succeeds-without-manifest-permissions-maybe-cors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the rule that such calls should only go to the originating server

This is know as the [Same Origin Policy](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy).

> How do browsers know it is ok to break this rule when comes to googleapis.com and, possibly, some others hosts?

If the host implements [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) then it can allow other origins (domains mainly, but also different website ports or protocols) to make AJAX requests to it and read the response.